# Japanese character width in textblock not same with one in editor visual studio extension

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, cjk

I'm developing an extension for visual studio but I have a problem with width of textblock display japanese character.

[image: Image discription]

As you can see the green line is the comment in visual studio editor and the black line is my Adornment text. I got typeface of editor by `IEditorFormatMapService` and set to my textblock. The english character is good but the width of japanese character is not correct.

My Project is on github: https://github.com/thuantan2060/comment-translator. You can find code set font style in `CommentTranslator/Ardonment/CommentAdornment.cs` file.

Thank you very much!